# Let $y = \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{64 + \sqrt{5096+ ...}}}$ and $\sqrt{4x^2 + \sqrt{16x^2 + \sqrt{64x^2 + ...}}} = 11 .$ What is the value of $x + y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let

$ y = \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{64 + \sqrt{5096 + \dots }}} $

and

$ \sqrt{4x^2 + \sqrt{16x^2 + \sqrt{64x^2 + \dots }}} = 11 . $

What is the value of $x + y$ ?

edit(1)

I've tried to squared both side of the first equations :

$ y^2 = 4 + \sqrt{64 + \sqrt{5096 + \dots }} $

from here, I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $4,64,5096,\ldots$ is not a sequence I recognise. Even if $5096$ were $4096$, it still wouldn't be clear what the next terms were.

Comment: @TonyK: If it were $4096$, it could be the terms of the sequence $\{4^{T_n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ for the triangular numbers $T_n$. Of course, it could be something else too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume here that it should be 4096.

If you factor out some fours, it's quite easy:
$$y=4\cdot \sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\ldots}}}}=4\cdot \sqrt{1+y} $$
and $y=8+4\sqrt{5}$.

With the same method I found that $x=\pm \frac{3\sqrt{11}}{2}$ because
$$11=2\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^2+\sqrt{x^2+\ldots}}}=2q \text{ with } q=\sqrt{x^2+q}.
$$